# $.isNumeric vs. isNaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any difference between [$.isNumeric](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) and `!isNaN()`?

I don't see where they will ever return different results.

Comment: whats your queries? not clear to me.

Comment: `isNaN()` specifically checks for the actual `NaN` value, very different.

Comment: @Arif -- it seems quite clear that the OP is asking what the difference is between `$.isNumeric` and `isNaN()`.

Comment: @Orbling Although it seems that `undefined` is also NaN.

Comment: I think it's rather confusing that `isNaN("123")` is false, but `isNaN("blah")` is true, even though they are both strings. FWIW, I can't see any differences: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ktxJb/

Comment: Scratch that: the empty string returns different results. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ktxJb/1/  (Thanks, Juhana)

Comment: @Blazemonger Sry, I know this post is 2 years old, but thought I would mention that it shouldn't be confusing that `isNaN("123")` should return false, because it *can be* a number even though it's a string. This is how it is used, to check if a string is a number. This is, I think, the idea behind needing this function in the first place. If I want to do a check on whether the data a user entered into a form can be converted to a number before I cause an error (although, I don't like jQuery's `isNumeric` because it accepts things like "0e5" and "0xFF" as a number), this is what I'd use.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the jQuery blog:

> Inside jQuery we’ve found several situations where we need to know if an argument is numeric, or would be successfully converted to a number if it is some other type. We decided to write and document jQuery.isNumeric() since it’s a useful utility. Pass it an argument of any type and it returns true or false as appropriate.

---

> jQuery.isNaN(): This undocumented utility function has been removed. It was confusing because it appropriated the name of a built-in JavaScript function but did not have the same semantics. The new jQuery.isNumeric() serves a similar purpose, but has the benefit of being documented and supported. Despite jQuery.isNaN() being undocumented, several projects on Github were using it. We have contacted them and asked that they use jQuery.isNumeric() or some other solution.

Also see the ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10478

---

jQuery's `isNumeric()` checks if a value is a number OR can be converted to a number.

**EDIT**

To further clarify what `isNan()` does (and what a NaN value is):

> A NaN, which means "Not-a-Number", is classified as a primitive value by the ECMA-262 standard and indicates that the specified value is not a legal number. The function returns true if the argument is not a number and false if the argument is a number.
>
> The classic example of a NaN is zero divided by zero, 0/0

```
Code: 
document.write(isNaN("Ima String")) 
document.write(isNaN(0/0)) 
document.write(isNaN("348")) 
document.write(isNaN(348)) 

Output: 
true 
true
false
false
```

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/isnan.html

Semi offtopic, but related is [this short talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: I think the OP is referring the native JS function, `isNaN()` -- not the jQuery version.

Comment: your update contradicts Orbling's comment above.  And from what I can gather, Orbling is correct.

Comment: If that was the case, `isNaN("123")` would be true, because a string is not a number. Instead it's false, because a string isn't `NaN`.

Comment: "A string isn't not-a-number." "I know many strings that are not-a-number." "No no, what those strings are, is not a number." -- with apologies to Rosencranz and Guildenstern

Comment: @KirkWoll: If I see `NaN` I just know what it means. Forgot that it might be useful to emphasize this. Thnx for letting me know!

Answer (score 14):

As PeeHaa says, `$.isNumeric()` checks whether the value is a number or can be converted to a number, `isNaN()` checks strictly only whether the value is `NaN`.

Here's a handy comparison chart that uses the [jQuery documentation's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) examples (comparing `$.isNumeric()` to `!isNaN` for easier comparison): http://jsfiddle.net/eghE9/

Comment: Thank you very much Juhana.  I've plugged it into my matrix of examples now.  http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/jQuery/Utilities/jQuery.isNumeric.cfm

Comment: If this answer starts with 'as PeeHaa says', and contains much less information than his answer, and was posted later, why was it accepted in favor of PeeHaa's answer? @Phillip

Comment: The table says it all. Using `!isNaN()` to check a number could lead to unexpected results.