# jQuery If value is NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble with an if statement. I want to set num to 0 of NaN:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {

var tal = $(this).val();
var num = $(this).data('boks');
if(isNaN(tal)) {
var tal = 0;
}
});
```

Comment: Then do it. Currently you are setting `tal` to `0`. Substitute `tal` with `num`.

Comment: Crazy how many views this question got..

Comment: To all users... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012807/isnumeric-vs-isnan i.e. USE $.isNumeric() !!!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You have to assign the value back to `$(this)`:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {

var tal = $(this).val();
var num = $(this).data('boks');
if(isNaN(tal)) {
var tal = 0;
}
$(this).data('boks', tal);
});
```

nicely written:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var eThis = $(this);
    var eVal = (isNaN(eThis.val())) ? 0 : eThis.val();
    eThis.data('boks', eVal);
});
```

Comment: eThis.val() is a String the 0 is a Number. Also you are using the global isNaN which is different from the better practice Number.isNaN (and its respective 1 liner polyfil). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: Your solution did not work for me then i used var tal = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;   it worked.

Answer (score 55):

If you want replace the NaN with 0, just write this:

```
var tal = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
```