# keypress function using name, where more than one same names exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, duplicates

**HTML**

```
<input name="pm" type="text" value="0"/>
<input name="pm" type="text" value="0"/>
<input name="pm" type="text" value="0"/>

<input name="total" type="text" value="0" disabled="disabled"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('[name="pm"]').keypress(function() {

//implementation ?

});
```

I have three text box by default value =0, as user write any one of the these three text box, total must be shown in total text box.
 Key press event working fine for all three text boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mZBtg/

Please note: I have used `keyup` api but it will give you same result what you are looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

You can also do `isNumeric` and `isNan` check; good link: [$.isNumeric vs. isNaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012807/isnumeric-vs-isnan) Also please see comments below. B-)

Feel free to play around and hope this help.

**code**

```
$('input[name="pm"]').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name="pm"]').each(function(){
        sum += parseInt(this.value);
    });
   $('input[name="total"]').val(sum);
});​
```

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/mZBtg/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mZBtg/2/) minor change to avoid NAN exception

Comment: @khaled_webdev brilliant and thanks bruv, this will give more stuff for OP to play around :) Thanks for the comment B-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="pm"]').keypress(function() {
  var total = $('[name="total"]');
  total.val(parseInt(total.val(), 10) + parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
});
```