# Is Number.IsNaN() more broken than isNaN()

Tags: javascript, nan, ecmascript-6

Soooooo `isNaN` is apparently broken in JavaScript, with things like:

```
isNaN('')
isNaN('   ')
isNaN(true)
isNaN(false)
isNaN([0])
```

Returning false, when they appear to all be... Not a Number...

In ECMAScript 6, the draft includes a new `Number.isNaN` but it looks like (imo) that this is also broken...

I would expect

```
Number.isNaN('RAWRRR')
```

To return true, since it's a string, and cannot be converted to a number... However...

[image]

It seems that things that I would consider... not a number, are indeed, not, not a number...

http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-isfinite-number

The examples on MDN say:

> Number.isNaN("blabla"); // e.g. this would have been true with isNaN

I don't understand how this is "More robust version of the original global isNaN." when I cannot check to see if things are not a number.

This would mean we're still subjected to doing actual type checking as well as checking isNaN... which seems silly...

http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-isnan-number

The ES3 draft here basically says, everything is always false, except with its Number.NaN

Does anyone else find this is broken or am I just not understanding the point of isNaN?

Comment: The isNaN() function determines whether a value is NaN or not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN It will return `true` **only** for `NaN`. String, boolean, ... is **not** a `NaN`.

Comment: @dfsq I dunno why *anyone* upvoted your comment because its entirely wrong. As it says in the MDN reference you linked, "coercion inside the isNaN function has interesting rules" . `isNaN({a:1})` will return true for example.

Comment: `''` is **not** "not a number". It coerces to 0, which is very much a number and not a `NaN`.

Comment: I agree that function is basically useless...

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`isNaN()` and `Number.isNaN()` both test if a value is (or, in the case of `isNaN()`, can be converted to a number-type value that represents) the `NaN` value. In other words, "NaN" does not simply mean "this value is not a number", it specifically means "this value is a *numeric* Not-a-Number value according to IEEE-754".

The reason all your tests above return false is because all of the given values can be converted to a numeric value that is not `NaN`:

```
Number('')    // 0
Number('   ') // 0
Number(true)  // 1
Number(false) // 0
Number([0])   // 0
```

The reason `isNaN()` is "broken" is because, ostensibly, type conversions aren't supposed to happen when testing values. That is the issue `Number.isNaN()` is designed to address. In particular, `Number.isNaN()` will *only* attempt to compare a value to `NaN` if the value is a number-type value. Any other type will return false, even if they are literally "not a number", because the *type* of the value `NaN` is number. See the respective MDN docs for [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).

If you simply want to determine whether or not a value is of the number type, *even if that value is `NaN`*, use `typeof` instead:

```
typeof 'RAWRRR' === 'number' // false
```

Comment: I would recommend: `typeof value === 'number' && !isNaN(value)`. Because `typeof NaN === 'number'`.

Comment: Frustrating that they introduced another method to check for NaN that is broken in many of the same ways (and in some new ones to boot).

Comment: @d512 Clearly you didn't understand this answer, because the entire point is that `isNaN` _isn't_ "broken". It's isn't checking whether the value is numeric (you can use `parseInt` or jQuery's `$.isNumeric` to do that) - `isNaN` is actually checking whether the value is `NaN`, which is a special value with a very specific meaning in JavaScript.

Comment: @Sean the Bean - I understood the answer fine. Correct implementation of a bad algorithm is still broken.

Comment: @d512: Just because you don't personally have a use case for checking if a value is NaN doesn't make it a bad algorithm, or broken. Perhaps you could propose the addition of a Number.isNumeric() function, though I'd be surprised if no one's done so already.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I figured that "is not a number" was really what it sounded like. I ran into a situation where isNaN('$1,234.56') evaluated to true but Number.isNaN('$1,234.56')  was false when updating my code and decided to switch over to the typeof here which solved my problem. Again thanks for explaining how this really works.

Answer (score 21):

No, the original `isNaN` is broken. You are not understanding the point of `isNaN`.

The purpose of both of these functions is to determine whether or not something has the value `NaN`. This is provided because `something === NaN` will always be `false` and therefore can't be used to test this. 
(side note: `something !== something` is actually a reliable, although counter-intuitive, test for `NaN`)

The reason `isNaN` is broken is that it can return `true` in cases when a value is not actually `NaN`. This is because it first coerces the value to a number.

So

```
isNaN("hello")
```

is `true`, even though `"hello"` is not `NaN`.

If you want to check whether a value actually is a finite number, you can use:

```
Number.isFinite(value)
```

If you want to test whether a value is a finite number or a string representation of one, you can use:

```
Number.isFinite(value) || (Number.isFinite(Number(value)) && typeof value === 'string')
```

Comment: Not quite: `Number.isFinite(parseFloat('1f'))` returns `true`

Comment: @GabrielFlorit You're right. I think I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in a comment `isNaN()` and `Number.isNaN()` both check that the value you pass in is not equal to the value `NaN`. The key here is that `NaN` is an actual value and not an evaluated result e.g. `"blabla"` is a `String` and the value is `"blabla"` which means it is not the value `"NaN"`.

A plausible solution would be doing something like:

```
Number.isNaN(Number("blabla")); //returns true.
```

Comment: Your solution still doesn't work in cases like `Number.isNaN(Number("    "))`.

Comment: @JLRishe Other possibilities: `const someValue = <anything>; !isNaN(+someValue)` or `const someValue = <anything>; !isNaN(parseFloat(someValue))`

Answer (score 7):

The key difference between the two is that the global `isNaN(x)` function performs a conversion of the parameter `x` to a number. So

```
isNaN("blabla") === true
```

because `Number("blabla")` results in `NaN`

There are two definitions of "not a number" here and that's perhaps where the confusion lies. `Number.isNaN(x)` only returns true for the IEEE 754 floating point specification's definition of Not a Number, for example:

```
Number.isNaN(Math.sqrt(-1))
```

as opposed to determining whether the object being passed in is of numeric type or not. Some ways of doing that are:

```
typeof x === "number"
x === +x
Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Number]"
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically, `window.isNaN` performs a type conversion to a number, then checks if it is NaN. Whereas, `Number.isNaN` doesn't try to convert its argument to a number. So  basically, you can think of `window.isNaN`, and `Number.isNaN` as working like so.

```
window.isNaN = function(n){
    return Number(n) !== Number(n);
}

window.Number.isNaN = function(n){
    return n !== n;
}
```

Please note that you don't need actually to use the `window.` to call `isNaN` or `Number.isNaN`. Rather, I am just using it to provide a better distinction between the two similarly-named methods to try to cut down on confusion.

~ Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

The following works because NaN is the only value in javascript which is not equal to itself.

```
Number.isNaN = Number.isNaN || function(value) {     
    return value !== value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Per, MDN, [it (NaN) is the returned value when Math functions fail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Description) and as such it is a specific value. Perhaps a better name would have been, `MathFunctionFailed`.

To determine if something is a number requires parsing which fails nicely over a broad range of non numeric inputs, successfully detecting numbers and strings representing numbers, hence:

`function isNumber(v) {return Number.isNaN(parseFloat(v)); }`

Comment: Something like `MathFunctionFailed` would have been *way* too verbose to get included in the standardization of floating point numbers in 1985. `NaN` and its semantic behavior, including the `NaN !== NaN` behavior, predate even the standardization process that led to IEEE-754, which in turn was well before JavaScript (or even the WWW) was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Number.isNaN**

```
alert(Number.isNaN('Hello')); // false
```

Shouldn't it return `true` because  `Hello` is a `string` and its `Not A Number` right ? But Lets know why it returns `false`.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) says :

> true if the given value is NaN and its type is Number; otherwise,
>   false.

Yes `Hello` value is `NaN` but the type is `string` , you can check the type as follows:

```
alert(typeof `Hello`);  // string
```

**Usage:**

Use when you want to check the value is both `NaN` and `type` is number.

**2. isNaN**

```
alert(isNaN('Hello')); // true
```

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) says:

> true if the given value is NaN; otherwise, false.

**Usage:**

Use when you want to check value is just NaN.

**3. jQuery.isNumeric()**

[Jquery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) Says :

> Determines whether its argument represents a JavaScript number.

```
alert($.isNumeric('Hello')); // false
alert($.isNumeric(3)); //true
```

**Usage:**

Use when you want to check value is a number or can be converted to a number.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012807/isnumeric-vs-isnan)

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple workaround to check Number.isNaN():

```js
    let value = 'test';
    Number.isNaN(-value); // true
    value = 42;
    Number.isNaN(-value); // false
```

js trying to convert the value to the negative Number, if the conversion is failed - we have NaN.

Simple, isn't it?

Moreover, online benchmark tests say Number.isNaN is lighter than isNaN.

Answer (score 1):

`Number.isNaN(x)` checks if x is directly evaluated to `NaN` or not.

`RAWR` is not the same as `NaN`.  Think of `NaN` as an entity to represent the result of some mathematical calculation where the computer does not know how to represent the number.

A mathematical operation is not going to yield a non-numeric result, hence the `typeof` `NaN` is `number`.

The string `RAWR` had undergone no mathematical operation to yield `NaN`.  However, if you were to call `Number.isNaN(+'RAWR')`, it would result in `NaN` since the unary `+` operator is trying to convert `'RAWR'` to a number.

On the other hand, `isNaN(y)` tells whether `y` can be converted to a number or not.  If `isNaN(y)` is `false`, `y` can be converted to a number.  But if `isNaN(y)` is true, `y` can **not** be converted to a number.

So a good rule of thumb is:

1. Do I want to check if `x` can be successfully converted to a number?  Use `isNaN(x) == false` in that case.  Unsuccessful conversion results in `NaN`.
2. Do I want to check if `x` is evaluated to `NaN`?  Use `Number.isNaN(x) == true` for that.

Answer (score 0):

@phill, as stated in other responses, neither is broken.

`Number.isNaN` work on a number or instance of `Number`, so even `Number.isNaN(new Date(NaN))` is false.

`isNaN`, on the other hand, is generic and  tries to convert its parameter to a number before checking it.

If you want to determine if a value is (or contains) `NaN`, you can use this function:

```
function valueIsNaN(value) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-self-compare
  return value !== value || typeof value == 'object' && Number.isNaN(value.valueOf());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**For example :**

```js
let name = "Tanvir Rifat";
let conversion = Number(name); // return NaN
```

if we check this two NaN it's return false because NaN is not identical `conversion === conversion` that means `NaN === Nan` (return false):

So that's why we need to check this using isNaN() & Number.isNaN()

```js
// using isNaN():
isNaN("Tanvir Rifat") // return true;
```

Because, behind the seen: isNaN() first convert this Number("Tanvir Rifat") which return NaN.

Then `isNaN(NaN)` returns `true`

```
// using Number.isNaN():
Number.isNaN("Tanvir Rifat") // return false;
```

Because, we know "Tanvir Rifat" is a String. And it is not a NaN type, if we check typeof "Tanvir Rifat" it returns 'string' which is not a NaN.

So that's why `Number.isNaN("Tanvir Rifat")` returns `false`. Because it's only check the NaN (and it doesn't coercion this value).