# Confusion between isNaN and Number.isNaN in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a confusion in how NaN works. I have executed `isNaN(undefined)` it returned `true`. But if I will use `Number.isNaN(undefined)` it is returning `false`.

So which one I should use? Also why there is so discrepancy in the result?

Comment: **Answer:** `Due to both equality operators, == and ===, evaluating to false when checking if NaN is NaN, the function Number.isNaN() has become necessary. In comparison to the global isNaN() function, Number.isNaN() doesn't suffer the problem of forcefully converting the parameter to a number. This means it is now safe to pass values that would normally convert to NaN, but aren't actually the same value as NaN. This also means that only values of the type number, that are also NaN, return true.`

Comment: didn't know about this. Most of the time I use isNaN()

Comment: Maybe use [Number.isFinite](https://mdn.io/Number/isFinite)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Number.IsNaN() more broken than isNaN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176459/is-number-isnan-more-broken-than-isnan)

Answer (score 109):

To quote from a [ponyfoo article on numbers in ES6](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-number-improvements-in-depth):

> Number.isNaN is almost identical to ES5 global isNaN method.
>   Number.isNaN returns whether the provided value equals NaN. This is a
>   very different question from “is this not a number?”.

So `isNaN` just checks whether the passed value is not a number or cannot be converted into a Number. `Number.isNaN` on the other hand only checks if the value is equal to `NaN` (it uses a different algorithm than `===` though).

The String `'ponyfoo'` for example is not a number and cannot be converted into a number, but it is not `NaN`.

Example:

```
Number.isNaN({});
// <- false, {} is not NaN
Number.isNaN('ponyfoo')
// <- false, 'ponyfoo' is not NaN
Number.isNaN(NaN)
// <- true, NaN is NaN
Number.isNaN('pony'/'foo')
// <- true, 'pony'/'foo' is NaN, NaN is NaN

isNaN({});
// <- true, {} is not a number
isNaN('ponyfoo')
// <- true, 'ponyfoo' is not a number
isNaN(NaN)
// <- true, NaN is not a number
isNaN('pony'/'foo')
// <- true, 'pony'/'foo' is NaN, NaN is not a number
```

Comment: In other words, it's not "almost identical" :)

Comment: @Nahn . . .  Correct. The quote even seems to contain a contradiction: "almost identical" vs. "very different question". IMHO, nils' answer is quite enlightening and doesn't need that confusing quote.

Comment: @BartHofland When it's talking about them being almost identical, it means how the code behind the functions execute are almost identical, isNaN just has one extra step that Number.isNaN skips, leading to very different results.

Comment: @Andrew Correct. I understand and I agree. But no matter how interesting that technical comparison of the implementation details may be, it only distracts attention from the *behavioral intent* of these two functions. Note that I do not consider one function to be "better" than the other. They just serve different purposes. I only wanted to support nils' excellent answer (excluding the confusing quote), because this answer enriched my understanding about the resulting functional differences, which makes choosing the right function for specific solutions a lot clearer and easier for me.

Answer (score 35):

- [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) converts the argument to a `Number` and returns true if the resulting value is `NaN`.
- [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) does not convert the argument; it returns true when the argument is a `Number` and is `NaN`.

> So which one i should use.

I am guessing you are trying to check if the value is something that *looks like a number*. In which case the answer is **neither**. These functions check if the value is an *IEEE-754 Not A Number*. Period. For example this is clearly wrong:

```js
var your_age = "";
// user forgot to put in their age
if (isNaN(your_age)) {
  alert("Age is invalid. Please enter a valid number.");
} else {
  alert("Your age is " + your_age + ".");
}
// alerts "Your age is ."
// same result when you use Number.isNaN above
```

> Also why there is so discrepancy in the result.

As explained above `Number.isNaN` will return false immediately if the argument is not a `Number` while `isNaN` first converts the value to a `Number`. This changes the result. Some examples:

```
                |       Number.isNaN()       |        isNaN()
----------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
value           | value is a Number | result | Number(value) | result
----------------+-------------------+--------+---------------+-------
undefined       | false             | false  | NaN           | true
{}              | false             | false  | NaN           | true
"blabla"        | false             | false  | NaN           | true
new Date("!")   | false             | false  | NaN           | true
new Number(0/0) | false             | false  | NaN           | true
```

Answer (score 20):

I found that if you want to check if something is numbery (or not), then a combination of `Number.isNaN()` with either `Number.parseInt()` or `Number.parseFloat()` (depending on what you expect) to cover most use cases:

consider:
test a bunch of different input vars against several is number tests:

```
r = [NaN, undefined, null, false, true, {}, [], '', ' ', 0, 1, '0', '1']
.map(function(v){return [
    v, 
    isNaN(v), 
    Number.isNaN(v), 
    Number.isInteger(v),
    Number.parseInt(v, 10), 
    Number.isNaN( Number.parseInt(v, 10)) 
];});
console.table(r);
// or if console.table() not available:
r.join('\n', function(v){v.join(',')} );
```

result:

```
NaN      , true , true , false, NaN, true 
undefined, true , false, false, NaN, true 
null     , false, false, false, NaN, true 
false    , false, false, false, NaN, true 
true     , false, false, false, NaN, true 
Object   , true , false, false, NaN, true 
Array(0) , false, false, false, NaN, true 
''       , false, false, false, NaN, true 
' '      , false, false, false, NaN, true 
0        , false, false, true , 0  , false
1        , false, false, true , 1  , false
'0'      , false, false, false, 0  , false
'1'      , false, false, false, 1  , false
```

Note the last column, which is usually what I want in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

In shortly,

`isNaN()`

> will check if the convert of value to Number (type) are failed

For example'abc'

---

`Number.isNaN()`

> will check if the given value type is Number but not valid number

For example: 'bb'/33

Answer (score 3):

First, forget about the useless meaning of the value `NaN`, just treat it as `bad number`. As soon as you saw `NaN`, read it as 'bad number'.

`Number.isNaN` is a more safe and robust version of `isNaN`, `isNaN` has a bug,

```
isNaN(NaN) // true, this is the supposed result, the argument is NaN
isNaN('hello') // true, but this is misleading, cuz `hello` is not NaN
```

`isNaN` can't distinguish `NaN` with other not-number values, such as characters.

So a new method comes into play.

Number.isNaN checks if the value is number firstly, if it is not a number, it returns false immediately.

`Number.isNaN('hello') // false, 'hello' is not NaN, this is the supposed result`

Answer (score 2):

**Number.isNaN()**

This method returns true if the value is of the type Number, and equates to NaN. Otherwise it returns false.
e.g.

```
Number.isNaN(123) //false

Type of 123 is number but 123 is not equal to NaN, therefore it returns false.


Number.isNaN('123') //false
    
Type of 123 is string & '123' is not equal to NaN, therefore it returns false.


Number.isNaN(NaN) //true

Type of NaN is number & NaN is equal to NaN, therefore it returns true.


Number.isNaN('NaN') //false

Type of 'NaN' is string & 'NaN' is not equal to NaN, therefore it returns false.
```

global **isNaN()** function

The global isNaN() function converts the tested value to a Number, then tests it.

```
isNaN(123) //false
isNaN('123') //false
isNaN(NaN) //true
isNaN('NaN') //true
```