# Why isNaN(undefined) !== Number.isNaN(undefined) is true

Tags: javascript

Why

```
isNaN(undefined) !== Number.isNaN(undefined)
```

is true.

Why  true

```js
console.log(isNaN(undefined)) //is true
```

But if I add `Number.`

```js
console.log(Number.isNaN(undefined)) // is false
```

Comment: Why do you think it would be otherwise?

Comment: Because they are both isNaN function, why they return different value if I add Number.

Comment: isNaN is not the same as Number.isNaN

Comment: Did you mean `!==`? Because `==!` in code will NOT do the same thing at all - it's an equality check `==` followed by a logical NOT `!`

Comment: [Confusion between isNaN and Number.isNaN in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164725)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) function "is a more robust version" of the global [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function. Specifically, the rules for the global `isNaN` function are odd and that's why `Number.isNaN` is typically preferred. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description.

According to that, `isNaN` essentially checks whether your value is not a number, whereas `Number.isNaN` checks whether your value is `NaN`. Of course, not all nonnumeric values are `NaN` - `"test"` for example, is not `NaN` but is also not a number.

Comment: "*isNaN essentially checks whether your value is not a number*" more specifically it checks if the value you supply *when converted to a number* produces `NaN`. So, `isNaN("123")` will report `false` because `Number("123")` does not result in `NaN`, although the value itself is definitely *not* a number but a string. However, `isNaN("hello")` returns `true` because `Number("hello")` does produce `NaN`. In short, yes - confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN` and `!anything` will always give you Booleans.

`parseFloat('27')` gives you the Number `27`.

`27` is not `false`, even with type conversion.