# Reversing an integer taken from event value: only works properly for the 1st event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Messing around with reversing a number from an Angular input.

Here is the method and property:

```
reversedIntInput = "";

  reverseInt(event: any) {
    const inputString = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    const parsed = parseInt(inputString);

    if (Number.isNaN(parsed) || inputString == "" || inputString === null) {
      this.reversedIntInput = "Nice try but this is not a number.";
    } else {
      this.reversedIntInput = inputString
        .split("")
        .reverse()
        .join("");
    }
  }
```

and here is the html:

```
<label>Reverse an Integer</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="reverseInt($event)">
<p>{{ reversedIntInput }}</p>
```

If I type "d" in the input, it does indeed display "Nice try but this is not a number."
if I type "45" in the input it does indeed display "54".

But if I type "54ddd" it just reverses it as a string and displays "ddd45" when it should display "Nice try but this is not a number."

Why is that? I console log both `inputString` and `parsed` and inputString continues to update when a letter is typed but parsed does not.

Comment: Add keydown event and when is pressed take ASCII code on pressed key, then check if asci code is >= 48 && <= 57, if is not event.preventDefault() to stop propagation or just return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check inputString have value and that value is a number, see this:

```
if (inputString  && Number(inputString)) {
   this.reversedIntInput = reverse logic .....
} else {
  this.reversedIntInput = "Nice try but this is not a number.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) returns a valid `Number` if you pass a string that starts with a number. It just ignores what comes after the number:

```js
const inputString = '54ddd';
const parsed = parseInt(inputString);

console.log(parsed); // prints 54
```

So when you are checking `Number.isNaN(parsed)` in this case, it will return `false`, because 54 is a valid `Number`.

Instead of `Number.isNaN`, you can use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) directly on your string (`inputString`), and it will work as you expect ([yes, Number.isNan and isNan are different functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164725/confusion-between-isnan-and-number-isnan-in-javascript)):

```
if (isNaN(inputString) || inputString == "" || inputString === null) {
```

When calling `isNan` on a string that is not entirely a number (even if it starts with one), it returns `true`:

```js
const inputString = '54ddd';

console.log(isNaN(inputString)); // prints true
```