# Why in my function parseInt doesn't return the 0 from the string I pass to it?

Tags: function, parseint

`parseInt` doesn't return 0 when I use it in the function below :

```
    const getGuestsCount = guestsInput => {
  if (parseInt(guestsInput)) {

    return parseInt(guestsInput);
  }

  return 'not a number';
};
```

For example, `getGuestsCount('0 we won\'t visit you!!');`
returns "not a number"

But if we use `parseInt` outside of the function then it's ok,
`parseInt('0 we won\'t visit you!!');`
returns 0 as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `parseInt('0 we won\'t visit you!!')` evaluates to `0`, your IF condition is negative and the function thus returns `not a number`.

Maybe you're looking for `if (!isNaN(parseInt(str)) { ... }`?

```
const getGuestsCount = guestsInput => {
  var guests = parseInt(guestsInput, 10);

  if (!isNaN(guests)) {
    return guests;
  }

  return NaN;
};
```

Also, checking for numbers in JavaScript is a bit cumbersome, you should check [Confusion between isNaN and Number.isNaN in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164725/confusion-between-isnan-and-number-isnan-in-javascript) and other suggested resources to better understand the problem.