# How can I restrict input on html to numbers with decimals using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I checked the answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input) and the best answer I found was this one since it doesn't allow to enter anything but numbers on the input field

```
function forceNumeric(){
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.val($input.val().replace(/[^\d]+/g,''));
}
$('body').on('propertychange input', 'input[type="number"]', forceNumeric);
```

The thing is that I need something like this but that it works for numbers with decimals. Right now this code prevents me from entering dots or commas so I can't enter decimal numbers. Any idea how to adapt it?

Comment: Just add dot/comma into character class: `/[^\d.,]+/g`

Comment: Simple, use `/[^\d,.]+/g` I think some research might have helped you and will do for future use. Look up Regular expression / regex and you will find documentation on how to use it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: simple answer is, you can't.  even using your regex, if you were to add `.` to the regex, you would *still* have to validate your input, because `12.3.45` isn't a number.  use the well formed and established `numeric` input box, and validate your input, like millions of other programs/sites/scripts.

Comment: also, the answers here and the comments are mostly a repeat of that popular question you posted, so I'm not sure how much use this question has for the site;  it's likely to be flagged as a duplicate of the question you referenced anyway.

Comment: @Claies I managed to do it. I will add my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by changing the type of input field from number to text and using this

```
function forceNumericDecimal(){
    var $input = $(this);
    $input.val($input.val().replace(',', '.'));
    $input.val($input.val().replace(/[^\d\.]+/g,''));
    $input.val($input.val().replace(/\./, "x"));
    $input.val($input.val().replace(/\./g, ""));
    $input.val($input.val().replace(/x/, "."));
}

$('body').on('propertychange input', '.numberdecimal', forceNumericDecimal);
```

The regex replacements will change commas for dots and will not allow more than one dot.

Comment: please note that this isn't a "JavaScript" solution, it is a solution that relies upon jQuery events.

Answer (score 1):

- Adjust your regexp to accept commas/dots:

  `/[^\d\.,]+/g`
- You are already using `type=number` which does the validation for you. Why do you even care about additional validation that does exactly the same thing as the native browser implementation?

Comment: Because if I use the type=number alone it allows the user to enter text on the input field and the validation is done afterwards while I want it to block the input of text completely.

Comment: In that case, you have more cases than just replacing "non-numerical" characters from the input. Eg. ``1.000.1`` is not a valid number, but your simple regexp will allow it.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No, I don't, as it is a rather complicated task. But a simple ``Number.isNaN(Number(your_input))`` should do the trick most of the times.

Comment: I tried that but it will not work really well because of the reasons stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176459/is-number-isnan-more-broken-than-isnan

Comment: Well, I've already told you: "it is a rather complicated task".