# How to check if unknown value is a valid number?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a value of type `unknown` and a configuration describing if that value must be an integer or float value. I started with this function

```
function isValueNumber(value: unknown, isAcceptingFloatingPointNumbers: boolean) {
  if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (!isAcceptingFloatingPointNumbers) {
    return Number.isInteger(value);
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

The problem is that when I call the function like so

```
isValueNumber("this is not a valid number", true)
```

it still returns `true` because my check `Number.isNaN` is not correct ( [Is Number.IsNaN() more broken than isNaN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176459/is-number-isnan-more-broken-than-isnan) )

Do you have any ideas how to fix this validator function?

Comment: Just check if it's a number. `typeof value === "number"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way, the function will return false if not a `number` :

```
function isValueNumber(value: unknown, isAcceptingFloatingPointNumbers: boolean) {
  if (typeof value !== 'number') {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (!isAcceptingFloatingPointNumbers) {
    return Number.isInteger(value);
  }
  
  return true;
}
```