# Why does new version of jQuery gives errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using Jquery 1.4.4.

I have updated to 1.10.2.

I am getting this errors:

jquery.ba-bbq.js

```
browser = $.browser,
mode = document.documentMode,
is_old_ie = browser.msie && ( mode === undefined || mode < 8 ),   //browser is undefined
```

jquery.color.js

```
jQuery.isNaN // jQuery.isNaN is not a function
```

Comment: [You need the jQuery Migrate plugin.](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin)

Comment: … or to update your plugins to modern versions / equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery BBQ project seem to be have been last updated in 2010.

The plugin supports

```
jQuery Versions 1.3.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.2
Browsers Tested Internet Explorer 6-8, Firefox 2-3.7, Safari 3-4, Chrome 4-5, Opera 9.6-10.1.
```

So, the new version of jQuery is not supported.  Also, note that 1.4.x to 1.10.x is quite a jump.  There are several breaking changes within the code.

Comment: I am mixing 2 projects, the other one needs a newer version, what can I do?

Comment: Mixing versions of jQuery is generally an extremely bad idea. You substitute one set of problems for another.

Comment: Any possible solution?

Comment: What is the new version of jQuery.isNaN?

Comment: @Pedro4441 Rather than repeating, See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012807/isnumeric-vs-isnan. You may be able to use `isNumeric()`.