# jquery check if value is not null / empty or NaN

Tags: jquery, asp.net

sI'm currently checking if value is Nan using jQuery and would like to extend the check to not null or empty as well but not sure on how to do this, 
here's my code;

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // ensure quantity textbox is numeric
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id$=txtQuantity]').change(function () {
        if(isNaN(this.value)) {
            alert("Please ensure the quantity specified is numeric");
            $(this).val("1");
        }
        else{
            $(this).val(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Change `if(isNaN(this.value)) {` to  `if(!this.value || isNaN(this.value)) {`

Comment: If think he probably wants `if(!this.value || isNaN(this.value))` in other words if its null or a NAN

Comment: @BenRobinson yes already edited. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change :

```
if(isNaN(this.value))
```

To

```
if(!this.value || isNaN(this.value)) ...
```

But why don't you use :

[jQuery.isNumeric](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) ?

So :

```
if(!jQuery.isNumeric(this.value)) {
            alert("Please ensure the quantity specified is numeric");
            $(this).val("1");
        }
        else{
            $(this).val(this.value);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can check for null directly like

`(myVar !== null)`

to check if the variable is empty you can do

`(myVar !== '')`

and for the numeric check either using `isNaN()` or `$.isNumeric()` may work but  `$.isNumeric()` return more accurate boolean [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8012858/3276081)

`(isNaN(myVar))` or `(!$.isNumeric(myVar))`

all together

`if ( (myVar !== null) || (myVar !== '') || (!$.isNumeric(myVar)) ){ ... }`